# Decrease the shipping cost as quantity increases

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I need adjust the shipping cost in Magento 2 with changing quantity.
Suppose ecommerece site is selling Laptops
Cost of shipping of 1 Laptop is $50
Now as quantity increases, I should be able to lower the shipping cost
for example
Cost of shipping for 2 laptops should be $80
Cost of shipping for 3 laptops should be $100
Cost of shipping for 4 laptops should be $110

and so on...
I am thinking about using https://amasty.com/shipping-rules-for-magento-2.html this extension. 
IF anybody knows it how to achieve this, I would be very thankful

Answer (score 1):

You can use magento's Table rate shipping method to achieve above things.

you can see more detail how to setup and use table rate:

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/shipping-table-rate.html

Use number of items vs destination to create proper csv.

Hope this will help